# VNC Connection Refused Problem Ubuntu Secondary router

Tags: linux, ubuntu, remote, vnc

Hello I installed VNC time ago but never worked until I went to the Ubuntu Wifi settings and enable Remote ON. After that worked with IP’s in 192.168.1.xxx. Now, I have a second router connected to the first router but this second router if you connect to its wifi networks it will provide you with IP’s in the range of 192.168.2.xxx and that second router is connected to PIA (privateinternetaccess). Then, if I connect the Ubuntu to the first router with IP’s of 192.168.1.xxx works very good. But If I connect the Ubuntu to the second router with IP’s of 192.168.2.xxx gives me connection refuse. What would be the problem? It’s the same Ubuntu. If connects to the IP’s 192.168.1.xxx why it doesn’t connect to the IP’s when is connected as 192.168.2.xxx? I don’t understand. In Windows and MacOs with just connect to another wifi network, the OS acquires the new IP and done, you enter in VNC as the new IP, easy like that. Here in Ubuntu just accept VNC with IP’s 192.168.1.xxx, if you connect to a wifi with other IP as 192.168.2xxx it doesn’t work, why and how can be fixed?

Thank you

Comment: Your description is not very clear. Is Ubunut the VNC server or the VNC client? Either way, where is the corresponding other end VNC client/server?

Comment: In a Ubuntu machine that has installed vnc, I can connect to it inside my network from other computers if I use my router that assigns to that ubuntu machine is of 192.168.1.xxx. If I connect the ubuntu machine to the router that assigns to it IP’s of 192.168.2.xxx then it can not connect, it says connection refuse from other computers. Why from other computers I can access if I have IP’s of 192.168.1.xxx in the ubuntu machine with vnc installed and if it has 192.168.2.xxx it doesn’t connect, it says connection refuse if I try to connect via other computers. That is the issue,